# How to get the coordinates of a picture that I drew in Python?

Tags: python

I saw one piece of code from a book. It draws a cat on the canvas.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, height=400, width=400)
c.configure(bg='dark blue', highlightthickness=10)
c.body_color = 'SkyBlue1'
body = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline=c.body_color, fill=c.body_color)
ear_left = c.create_polygon(75, 80, 75, 10, 165, 70, outline=c.body_color, fill=c.body_color)
ear_right = c.create_polygon(255, 45, 325, 10, 320, 70, outline=c.body_color, \
fill=c.body_color)
foot_left = c.create_oval(65, 320, 145, 360, outline=c.body_color, fill= c.body_color)
foot_right = c.create_oval(250, 320, 330, 360, outline=c.body_color, fill= c.body_color)
eye_left = c.create_oval(130, 110, 160, 170, outline='black', fill='white')
pupil_left = c.create_oval(140, 145, 150, 155, outline='black', fill='black')
eye_right = c.create_oval(230, 110, 260, 170, outline='black', fill='white')
pupil_right = c.create_oval(240, 145, 250, 155, outline='black', fill='black')
mouth_normal = c.create_line(170, 250, 200, 272, 230, 250, smooth=1, width=2)
c.pack()
```

Question:
How to get all the coordinates of the cat? If I draw it on paper, it is quite time-consuming. I wonder if there is an online tool that allows you to draw the image/cat in the coordinate system? So you can put all the coordinates in the code. I searched online but did not find a good one. Because:

1. In Python (0,0) starts from the top-left. Normally in Math (0,0) starts from the center.
2. In Python, the unit is pixel. The number(such as 400x400) is quite big, I need to change the maximum value of x and y in that tool(if there is such a tool).
   Any suggestion?
   Thanks.

Comment: If origin (start point of coordinate system) and scale (numbers are big) are your only problems: You can move the origin by adding and subtracting and you can change the scale by multiplication and division. You can read more about that e.g. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/2d_transformation.htm). But I see a  lot bigger problems when it comes to calculating coordinates and result representation.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the coordinates"? Like the coordinates of all pixels filled with your content? Or just a [bounding box](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/basics-of-bounding-boxes-94e583b5e16c) surrounding your picture?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, "all the coordinates" is kind of key coordinates/points, such as the coordinates of the mouth.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it appears to be quite a complex task. If you want to remember the "key" coordinates, then you're gonna to compute them yourself. For example you can represent the process of face drawing as a number of certain steps (draw main shape, draw nose, draw mouth, draw left eye and so on), and define how you track their coordinates separately.

The next code might not work as is (I didn't test it, but it shows a general idea)

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, body_center, body_radius, body_color):
        self.body_center = body_center
        self.body_radius = body_radius
        self.body_color = body_color

    def draw_normal(self, canvas):
        self.body = self._draw_body(canvas, self.body_color)
        self.mouth = self._draw_mouth_normal(canvas, 'black')
        
    def _draw_body(self, canvas, color):
        x, y = self.body_center
        r = self.body_radius
        body_coords = (x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)
        body = canvas.create_oval(*body_coords, outline=color, fill=color)
        return body

    def _draw_mouth_normal(self, canvas, color):
        x, y = self.body_center
        y += 0.4*self.body_radius 
        width, height = (0.36*self.body_radius, 0.133*self.body_radius)
        mouth = canvas.create_line(x-width/2, y-height/2, x, y+height/2, x+width/2, y-height/2, smooth=1, width=2)
        return mouth
    
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, height=400, width=400)
c.configure(bg='dark blue', highlightthickness=10)
c.body_color = 'SkyBlue1'
cat = Cat(body_center=(200,185), body_radius=165, body_color=c.body_color)
cat.draw_normal(c)
c.pack()
```

Here you create an object of a `Cat`, define where is body center and how big it is, and then e.g. mouth is drawn *relatively* to this body, by coordinates computed in the program. You can then remember the respective X and Y of each part in some list,  if you need these coordinates